# Play Framework 2 / How to ensure years with 4 digits from form's input date?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I use PlayFramework 2.1 with Scala as main language.

I have a web form with an input date.
I want to force user to enter a date following this pattern: `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Therefore, I precise the pattern like this in my controller:

```
 val myForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "date" -> date("dd/MM/yyyy")
    )(MyModel.apply)(MyModel.unapply)
  )
```

However, pattern like `dd/mm/yyy` is accepted too.... for instance: `17/02/201` instead of `17/02/2013`. 
On the contrary, `dd/mm` isn't accepted, what I expect.

Is there an efficient and clean way to guarantee the expected pattern with 4 digits for the year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at it from a slightly different angle. You probably want to ensure the year is greater than 999 (maybe even higher).

In order to do that you need to `verify` your mapping. To do that you can create a `Constraint` similar to this:

```
def minYear(minYear: Int): Constraint[Date] = 
  Constraint[Date]("constraint.minYear", minYear) { o =>
    if (o.getYear >= minYear) Valid
    else Invalid(ValidationError("error.minYear", minYear))
  }
```

You can then use it like this:

```
val myForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "date" -> date("dd/MM/yyyy").verifying(minYear(999))
  )(MyModel.apply)(MyModel.unapply)
)
```

Don't forget to add `constraint.minYear` and `error.minYear` to your [`messages`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaI18N) file.

Comment: I would suggest to replace `Constraint[Date]("constraint.minYear", minYear)` by merely `Constraint[Date]("constraint.minYear")`. `minYear` would be found as being part of closure.

Comment: The Play Framework documentation of `Contraint` states `@param args the message arguments, to format the constraint name`. The construction I used is exactly the same as the available default validations in the [Validation.scala](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.0/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/validation/Validation.scala) file.